# (SQL/PLSQL) Display updated rows during trigger

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

```
create or replace trigger add_trips 
  AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE ON TRIP
DECLARE
  trip_num DRIVER.TRIPS%TYPE; 
BEGIN  
  UPDATE DRIVER SET trips = (SELECT COUNT(L#) AS NUMOFTRIPS FROM TRIP WHERE 
  DRIVER.L# = TRIP.L#) 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TRIP.L# FROM TRIP WHERE TRIP.L# = DRIVER.L#);
END;
```

is there a way i can display updated rows after a trigger has run?

Comment: You could, but you shouldn't because the trigger could be executed from anywhere that does an update, and while your app might expect a result set to come back, its likely that other callers may not.

Comment: is there an alternative way of doing it without the trigger?

Comment: If your app needs to display the list, then do a select after your update. Presumably, you know, or can derive, the set of data that was updated. You could also do the update as a stored procedure that updates the trip and the driver, then can query whatever you like. Problem with triggers is they tend to be relatively hidden, unless you go looking for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the number of updated/inserted rows you can display those via the dbms-output using:

```
 dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount || ' rows updated/inserted.');
```